# Error when compiling PCL for ROS groovy install from source on Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile groovy from source on my Ubuntu 12.04.1 to help me understand catkin better and also so I can compile on my BeagleBone later. I followed the instructions on

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source

When I run:

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

I get:

```
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/sameer/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'
[  0%] Built target pcl_io_ply
[  0%] Built target pcl_octree
[  1%] Built target pcl_pcd_convert_NaN_nan
[  1%] Built target pcl_ply2ply
[  2%] [  3%] Built target pcl_ply2obj
Built target pcl_ply2raw
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_common.so
Scanning dependencies of target pcl_plyheader
[  3%] Building CXX object io/tools/ply/CMakeFiles/pcl_plyheader.dir/plyheader.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsensor_msgs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lroscpp_serialization
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrosconsole
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrostime
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_common.so.1.6.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/pcl_plyheader
[  3%] Built target pcl_plyheader
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'pcl': 
  Command '/home/sameer/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> /home/sameer/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53401/error-when-compiling-pcl-for-ros-groovy-install-from-source-on-ubuntu-12.04.1/) by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a fix for that [here](https://github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-release/commit/bf43ffc0eebca4042c6765319c4dd211409d7ace)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on 2013-01-25**:
Thanks. I had to apply the patches in this history as well:

https://github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-release/commits/bf43ffc0eebca4042c6765319c4dd211409d7ace/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake